# How to populate a specific cell range with DB2 variables

Tags: vba, excel

I need to populate cell values from DB2.

Below is my column structure in Excel.

```css
Contract Number   

Party Type Code   
Surname   
First Name   
Date Of Birth   
Address Line-1   
City   
Province Code   
Postal Code   
Country Code   
Country Text   
 
Party Type Code   
Surname   
First Name   
Date Of Birth   
Address Line-1   
City   
Province Code   
Postal Code   
Country Code   
Country Text
```

I have a working connection from Excel to DB2.

My requirement is to pass contract number field from Excel to DB2 and fetch the corresponding details.

There could be multiple rows having the same contract number, as in this case.

As of now, I am populating individual fields and then assigning them to the cell values.

```css
strSQL = "SELECT CONTRACT_NUM FROM " & Region & "." & Table & " WHERE CONTRACT_NUM=" & CONTRACTNO & " fetch first row only;"

Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row_num).Value = rs.Fields(0).Value
```

Is there a simpler way to populate all the fields simultaneously ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First step: Change your SQL statement so that it returns all columns you want.

```
strSQL = "SELECT CONTRACT_NUM" _ 
       & "      , Party_Type_Code" _
       & "      , Surname" _
       & "      , First_Name" _ 
       (...)
       & " FROM " & Region & "." & Table _
       & " WHERE CONTRACT_NUM=" & CONTRACTNO & " fetch first row only;"
```

Second step: Write data to your sheet. There are several ways to do so:

The easiest way to get data from a Recordset into a sheet is using the Range-Command `CopyFromRecordset`. This will write all data into the Excel sheet, so you could try:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row_num).CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

If you want to write the data indiviually, the easiest way is to use the Recordset-Command `GetRows` that writes the data into a (zero-based) 2-dimensional array. Just be aware that the first index is the column, the second the row.

The following code would basically do the same as the statement above, just to get you the idea:

```
Dim data As Variant
data = rs.GetRows
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row_num)
Dim colIndex As Long, rowIndex As Long

For colIndex = 0 To UBound(res, 1)
    For rowIndex = 0 To UBound(res, 2)
        r.Offset(rowIndex, colIndex) = res(colIndex, rowIndex)
    Next rowIndex
Next colIndex
```

**Note**: Both examples assumes that your SQL-Code works, the RecordSet is created and contains data. For a robust solution, you have to add error handling for example for the case the SQL statement didn't return any data.